# Will xbox data be erased if I convert my USB drive back to PC format?

Tags: xbox-360, hardware

Earlier this semester, I transferred my xbox profile along with some game data to a USB drive so I could bring it with me when I went to my friend's dorm to play Borderlands. I now need to use the drive for an English presentation in a few days, but I can't remember whether or not I transferred the files back to my xbox hard drive, and my roommate went home earlier and took our TV with him so I can't check. If I do reformat the USB, will I potentially lose my data if it's still on there? Or is there a way for me plug it into my laptop and check the contents before it gets reformatted?

Comment: If you format your USB stick, everything on it will be *gone*.

Comment: It should be in a hidden folder called `XBOX360`. Set your PC to show hidden files and you'll be able to see what's on the USB drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you format a drive, regardless of type and resulting format, all data on the drive is erased.  See if the drive is readable on your PC before you format it.  If it is, you shouldn't need to format it at all.  If not, make sure you back up the data *again* (find a TV and an XBox) before you reformat.

In any case, once you format the drive, you're hosed if you don't have a backup.

Comment: The drive should be readable on the PC. What it sees is a folder full of "junk" data files -it doesn't know how to read actual savegames-.